# Yii: How to authenticate using two different tables

Tags: authentication, module, yii

Does anyone know how to do separate login forms and authenticate on two different tables? 
I can't go with one table and different roles... client requested to do separate tables...

I've got user login system based on Yii framework login system. But now I have to do separate for admin user (administration module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this issue was to create two identical copies of this plugin from the Yii Framework library:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/

Then I refactored it and called it "Customer" and changed the config so that it used a different table etc.

In the configuration options for Yii, I also included these options to keep the sessions separate (config/main.php):

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'user' => array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
        'class' => 'RWebUser', // added - possibly uses the Rights user manager
    ),
    'customer' => array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => array('/customer/login'),
        'stateKeyPrefix' => 'customer',
    ),
    'customerUser' => array(
        'class' => 'CWebUser',
        'stateKeyPrefix' => 'customer',
        'loginUrl' => array('/customer/login'),
    ),
```

Comment: I could provide a download link on my blog to the refactored/modified code if anyone would like?

Comment: First, yii-user is a user-contributed extension—it is *not* part of the Yii Framework. Second, users should know what they are getting into with yii-user. It appears to have been abandoned by its author and nobody else has picked it up. Look at the issues list (50 open, nearly all of them unreviewed by the autohor). Be prepared to maintain it yourself so read the code first (take a look at the Profile model, for example). It's password handling is dismally insecure. I found it needed *a lot* of work and in the end wasn't worth it.

Comment: @KieranAndrews I would like if You don't mind :) And thank You!

Comment: @KieranAndrews Hi. Do You remember about me? :)

Comment: @KieranAndrews Or if You don't want to publish this code on Your blog, can You send me it to lukas.openid@gmail.com?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to your `UserIdentity` component called, for example, role. Then change the `authenticate()` method of UserIdentity so that it fetches from the account table corresponding to role. Now you need to make sure that `UserIdentity->role` is set before invoking `UserIdentity->authenticate()`. If you are following the `yiic webapp` template then this would be in `SiteController`. Two very easy ways (among others):

1. Have two different login pages, one for normal users and one for admins and each has its own URL. Implement it with two views and two login action methods in `SiteController`, each sets up `UserIdentity->role` appropriately before invoking `UserIdentity->authenticate()`. This approach duplicates code and you'll be able to see how to sort that out once it's working.
2. Use one login page with a form element (checkbox perhaps) that an admin user selects. This form's action method `UserIdentity->role` according to form state.